# collection automatically triggers method

Tags: c#, .net, observablecollection

I am looking for a collection object that calls a method by it self after the count reaches 1000. Here in the example when the count of element reach 1000 i want to process them.

Example:

```
internal static Collection<string> elements=new collection<string>

public void someMethod()
{
    XDocument XD = null;
    XD = XDocument.Load("https://somewebservice.asp");
    var Value = XD.Descendants().where(x => x == "someAttribute").FirstorDefault();
    if(value != null)
    {
        elements.Add(value);
    }
    if(elemets.count() == 1000)
    {
        // Do Something
        // But i dont want to check the count every time 
        // I want the collection object to do the thing.. is there any method
        // that can do this?
    }
}
```

Comment: No, there is not. You need to roll your own.

Comment: What's wrong with checking the count every time? You won't notice a performance hit if that's what you're worried about

Comment: @MichaelB What if the collection is modified in many different locations?  What if you don't control all of those locations (i.e. you pass the collection as an interface to external code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an `ObservableCollection` which fires an event when the colleciton is changed.  You can check the count at this time and do something.

```
var collection = new ObservableCollection<int>();
collection.CollectionChanged += (s, args) =>
{
    if (collection.Count == 1000)
        DoSomething();
};
```

Comment: @EtienneMaheu There is nothing wrong in using `ObservableCollection`. Also it won't fire any event in `Dispatcher`.

Comment: @EtienneMaheu That's going to be a minuscule overhead that's almost certainly not going to be a serious problem. In the actual event that the use of this type results in a program that performs unacceptably poorly, and performance benchmarking reveals this to be a significant source of the problem, which I *highly* doubt would happen, then sure, a custom implementation can be written to attempt to tweak the performance to the needs of the specific application. Doing so without a compelling need however is wasteful of developer time and is going to be more error prone than using a tested type.